# Get Selected lookup ID from javascript method

Tags: visualforce, javascript

There are already some questions about this but i did not find a working solution.

I'm trying to access in a javascript function the selected lookup value ID of an input field.

Do you know how can i do that?

My VF component:

```
<apex:component Controller="FController" extensions="FCompExtension" allowDML="true">  
    <apex:attribute name="recordId" description="Record Id" type="id" assignTo="{!record_Id}" required="true"/>   
    <apex:form >
    <script>
        function ShowChinaOfficeSelection(){
            //First Way, doesn t work
            var SalesOrgId= '{!NewAccountForLFC.Sales_Org__c}'; 
            //Second Way, this gives me the text value
            var SalesOrgId=document.getElementById('{!$Component.lookupfield}').value;  
            console.log('SelectedSalesOrdId '+SalesOrgId);      

         }
    </script>

  <!-- LookUp Field -->
  <apex:inputfield value="{!NewAccountForLFC.Sales_Org__c}" onchange="ShowChinaOfficeSelection()" id="lookupfield"> 
  </apex:inputField>     


 </apex:form>     
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hidden field rendered in the page which corresponds to the lookup field. This hidden field contains the ID of the lookup value after the selection is made in the lookup dialog.

It is named the same as the lookup field's (visible) textbox and is suffixed with `_lkid`.

```
var SalesOrgText = document.getElementById('{!$Component.lookupfield}').value;
var SalesOrgId = document.getElementById('{!$Component.lookupfield}_lkid').value;

console.log('SelectedSalesText: ' + SalesOrgText);
console.log('SelectedSalesOrgId: ' + SalesOrgId);
```

Given a page like this:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" id="thePage">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:inputField id="theInput" value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

An `input:text` field will be rendered with the id: `thePage:theForm:theInput` which will contain the name of the record which was selected.

As well as an `input:hidden` field with the id: `thePage:theForm:theInput_lkid` which will store the selected record's id value.

Comment: Fantastic explanation Mark!

Comment: What is the !$Component here? the VF page or VF component?

Comment: It is a DOM element. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Comment: can we access this through jQuery?

Comment: Create a question of your own regarding accessing a DOM element using this syntax via jQuery and any problems you're having doing so. Comments are not the place for a conversation about an altogether different question. -- nevermind, I see that you did create a question.

Comment: How about the id that generated from apex:repeat? How we can capture it from Javascript?