# How to get selected record Id from apex:inputField in javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a apex:inputField where I'm getting lookup field. Now I want to get the Id of that selected record in lookup field in my javascript.

I'm able to get the record name but not record id

**VF Page:**

```
 <apex:inputField id="accountName" value="{!Oppty.AccountId}" onchange="accountSelected(this.value);" />

function accountSelected(data){
        console.log(' >>> Account changed... '+JSON.stringify(data));
    }
```

Comment: did the answer solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Id of the selected record in your JavaScript function, you can try modifying the `accountSelected` function to below.

It is named the same as the lookup field's (visible) textbox and is suffixed with _lkid.

```
function accountSelected(data) {
    var selectedAccountId =document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountName}_lkid').value;
    console.log(' >>> Account Id changed... ' + selectedAccountId);
}
```

you can check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70833/get-selected-lookup-id-from-javascript-method) similar Thread

Comment: I'm getting below error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at accountSelected

Comment: did you tried as given above ?

Comment: yes I did as given above